# Dashed \Uparrow

Tags: symbols

I'm trying to define a dashed `\Uparrow`: my first try, using `tikz`, consists simply in drawing two white rectangle over the normal `\Uparrow`, manually trying to find a good positioning of the rectangles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\Dasheduparrow}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1, y=1]
\node (0,0) [inner sep=0] {$\Uparrow$};
\fill[fill=white] (-3,0.5) rectangle (2,-1);
\fill[fill=white] (-3,-2) rectangle (2,-3.5);
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

By typing now

```
\begin{document}
Text $\Dasheduparrow$ $\Downarrow$ $\Uparrow$ text.
\end{document}
```

I get this

[image: 1]

and I'm quite satisfied with the output. However, I've got three questions:

1. How to get the same alignment of the normal `\Downarrow` and `\Uparrow`? My new symbol is aligned with the baseline of the text, while the two default ones are a little down-shifted.
2. How to make this new symbol correctly stretchable? By doing `\LARGE Text $\Dasheduparrow$ $\Downarrow$ $\Uparrow$ text.` the output is
   [image: 2]
   where it's evident that the underlying `\Uparrow` has been enlarged, while the white rectangles have not.
3. Is there a better solution than the one I proposed?

Comment: vertical arrows, like all binary and relational operators, are vertically centered on the math axis (the same position as the horizontal bar on a plus sign).  this probably won't help you lower the dashed arrow, but it explains why the other two are positioned as they are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**REVISED ANSWER**

The OP comments that, with my original answer, the gaps are not scaled at different font sizes (and math styles).  This can be remedied by dispensing with `tikz` and employing my `stackengine` package, while scaling the gap size with the math style (using the `scalerel` package's `\LMex` [Local-Mathstyle ex] rather than `cm` or `pt` as the dimension of the white rectangle overlays).

To answer another question of the OP, the `\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}` syntax allows the current mathstyle to be carried into a construct where it would normally be lost, in this case, into the `\hbox` that is being `\vcenter`ed and stacked.  It is equivalent to a glorified `\mathchoice`, but will frequently lessen the amount of typing necessary by a significant amount.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine,xcolor}
\newcommand{\Dasheduparrow}{\ThisStyle{\vcenter{\hbox{$%
\stackengine{0.45\LMex}{\stackengine{-.15\LMex}{$\SavedStyle\Uparrow$}
  {\textcolor{white}{\rule{1.1\LMex}{0.3\LMex}}}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}%
 }{\textcolor{white}{\rule{1.1\LMex}{0.3\LMex}}}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}%
$}}}}
\begin{document}
Text $\Dasheduparrow$ $\Downarrow$ $\Uparrow$ text.

$\Dasheduparrow \scriptstyle \Dasheduparrow \scriptscriptstyle \Dasheduparrow$

\LARGE
Text $\Dasheduparrow$ $\Downarrow$ $\Uparrow$ text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Here, I start with the OP's definitions.

However, I then use `\vcenter` to center it on the math axis, and also use `scalerel` features to preserves the math style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand{\Dasheduparrow}{\ThisStyle{\vcenter{\hbox{$
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1, y=1]
\node (0,0) [inner sep=0] {$\SavedStyle\Uparrow$};
\fill[fill=white] (-3,0.5) rectangle (2,-1);
\fill[fill=white] (-3,-2) rectangle (2,-3.5);
\end{tikzpicture}$}}}}
\begin{document}
Text $\Dasheduparrow$ $\Downarrow$ $\Uparrow$ text.

$\Dasheduparrow \scriptstyle \Dasheduparrow \scriptscriptstyle \Dasheduparrow$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ok, now the vertical alignment of the symbol is good! What about the stretchability? In your example you've got the same problem as mine, i.e. the `\Uparrow` on the background strecthes correctly, while the white rectangles do not... Another little question: what are the `\ThisStyle` and `\SavedStyle` commands doing here? Are they necessary?

Comment: @Rackbox Please see my revised answer.

Answer (score 2):

A quick workaround (may be a little unclean):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz,calc}

\newcommand{\Dasheduparrow}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1, y=1]
\node (0,0) [inner sep=0] {$\Uparrow$};
\fill[fill=white] (-3,0.5) rectangle (2,-1);
\fill[fill=white] (-3,-2) rectangle (2,-3.5);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
Text \parbox{\widthof{$\Dasheduparrow$}}{$\Dasheduparrow$} $\Downarrow$ $\Uparrow$ text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Where I have used a `parbox` to center its contents.

```
\parbox{\widthof{$\Dasheduparrow$}}{$\Dasheduparrow$}
```

Another possibility is to use the math centering command:

`\vcenter{\hbox{\Dasheduparrow}}`